# Java for making a game in Keying

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

So this is my full keying.java:

```
package com.Bench3.mygame;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Keying extends JPanel {

    public Rectangle character;

    public int charW = 24;
    public int charH = 36;

    public boolean right = false;
    public boolean left = false;

    public Keying(Display f, Images i){
        character = new Rectangle(180, 180, charW, charH);

        f.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){ // <-- line 20
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
                if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D){
                    right = true;
                    character.x += 1;
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A){
                    left = true;
                    character.x -= 1;
                }
            }

            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
                if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D){
                    right = false;
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A){
                    left = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(character.x, character.y, character.width, character.height);

        if(right){
            character.x += 1;
        }
        if(left){
            character.x -= 1;
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

the code **f.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){** (line 20)

I am trying to make a game, and the keying java is the only problem I have, I am following a guide by a video, and I am doing exactly what he did but I am getting errors.

Errors:

```
Description: KeyAdapter cannot be resolved to a type
Resource: Keying.java
Path: /My First Game In Java/src/com/Bench3/mygame
Location: line 20
Type: Java Problem

The method addKeyListener(KeyListener) in the type Component is not applicable for the arguments (new KeyAdapter(){})
```

Comment: What you do not want to do on StackOverflow is post your code essentially saying "here's my code fix it". We need specific errors, stack traces etc. otherwise you're on the fast track to a closed question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to use `KeyAdapter` but you are not importing it. [`KeyAdapter` is in `java.awt.event`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyAdapter.html). You are importing `java.awt.*` and `java.awt.event.KeyEvent`. Neither of these will bring in `java.awt.event.KeyAdapter`.

You will need to import `java.awt.event.KeyAdapter` as well.

In general, errors like "KeyAdapter cannot be resolved to a type" mean that the compiler could not find a class named "KeyAdapter" anywhere. This usually points to a missing import or a typo.

Just to point this out: importing `java.awt.*` does not import subpackages of `java.awt`, e.g. it does not automatically bring in `java.awt.event.*`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely that the character Rectangle needs to be final:

```
public final Rectangle character;
```

When you have anonymous classes ( `f.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){...})` -> the `KeyAdaptor` is an anonymous class) they need 'final' instances to work on otherwise they don't know if the `character` Rectangle has changed between when the class was instantiated, and when it was called.

Comment: Ok, I added in the 'final' in the code above, it still has the error, what next?

Comment: The final-character problem is just the next problem you will have, it seems, not the current one with the wrong imports.